# Is it possible to make BEA Portal 9.2 close link and meta tags with '/>' so they are XHTML valid?

Tags: validation, xhtml, standards-compliance, bea

I'm trying to make a BEA Portal website XHTML compliant, because this has been written in the contract with the client, and I'm stuck on this problem: BEA renders `<meta>` and `<link>` tags without the closing slash, i.e. `<link/>` and `<meta/>` as it is required by XHTML.

When I look at the documentation from BEA it seems that it should be possible to make it render the tags with a closing slash: [The skin.properties file (edocs.bea.com)](http://edocs.bea.com/wlp/docs81/lookandfeel/lookandfeel.html#999045).

Is it possible to change the redering with a configuration directive? Or perhaps, to hook into the underlying redering method so that I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try a tag-rewriting filter implemented either as a rewrite rule in a reverse proxy or as a filter servlet.  Wouldn't suggest looking for the answer in the portal itself...

Answer (score 1):

For software that doesn't use XML serializer, XHTML is pointless (see numerous other questions on SO about XHTML).

If you want to make page more standards-compliant, I suggest aiming for HTML4.01 Strict or HTML5 (with CSS for layout of course – it's not XHTML-specific thing).

Comment: I totally agree that there is no point in choosing XHTML over HTML. Unfortunately, I'm not the one making this decision. =)